# Connection between Start Variable and Function Variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn C# in Unity. Thought maybe I could get by without it for a while as it's just a personal project, but it has caught up with me. I know that myInt = 5 is passed to MultiplyByTwo(myInt). But then, is MultiplyByTwo in Start connecting to the MultiplyByTwo function and carrying myInt with it and placing myInt into number. I think I understand the rest after that. I'm just having trouble seeing the connection between myInt in Start and number in MultiplyByTwo.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class VariablesAndFunctions : MonoBehaviour
{   
    int myInt = 5;


    void Start ()
    {
        myInt = MultiplyByTwo(myInt);
        Debug.Log (myInt);
    }


    int MultiplyByTwo (int number)
    {
        int ret;
        ret = number * 2;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what you meant by connection, But I can say what is actually happening here:

- The variable `myInt` is initialized with `5`
- Then you called the `MultiplyByTwo()` by passing the value of `myInt`
- Which means, the value(`5`) will be assigned to the variable `number` in the  `MultiplyByTwo()` method.
- There you were processing the calculation and returning the result from the method to the `Start()`
- Finally the return value is assigning to the `myInt`, so the value of old variable changes.

You can realize these steps if you go through each lines during debugging